# Using sed to swap Windows location for Mac

Tags: bash, service, sed, finder, automator

I am writing a bash script for an automator service that will take a Windows directory location and change it to Mac and open a finder window. It's working except for when it hits folders with spaces. I have put in to remove them but it won't work on anything with spaces still. I must have made some sort of syntax mistake.

```
sed -e 's:\\\\fmg_cifs1\\Dept_Shares:/Volumes/Dept_Shares:' -e 's: :\ :g' -e 's:\\:/:g' | pbcopy
TAG=$(pbpaste)
cd $TAG; open .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly all you have to change:

```
cd "$TAG"
```

Quoting fixes everything!

Do you need to use `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` and a variable?

```
cd "$(sed -e 's:\\\\fmg_cifs1\\Dept_Shares:/Volumes/Dept_Shares:' -e 's: :\ :g' -e 's:\\:/:g')"
```

As Jonathan pointed out, some of the `sed` command is unnecessary. Of course, something needs to be fed to `sed`. This may be all you need:

```
cd "$(echo "$dir" | sed -e 's:\\\\fmg_cifs1\\Dept_Shares:/Volumes/Dept_Shares:')"
```

Comment: Do you still need to put the backslash in front of the spaces with `sed` if you enclose everything in double quotes?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The one escaped space doesn't need to be escaped regardless. I didn't even notice that. The whole last part of the `sed` command can be removed (unless there are other backslashes that need replacing).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thanks a ton man. I tried quotes all over that spot but was using escape characters because I thought it would just put in $TAG for the location and not the actual data. The reason I used is because the service takes the higlighted text and uses it as input. I'm pretty new to bash still so I mostly modified that existing solution that was from mac to windows.

Comment: Given that the names seem to be coming from Windows, the backslash to slash mapping is probably sensible.  I also note that if there's a name with drive letters like `C:\Some Where\Having Names With\Or\WithoutSpaces` then the `C:` needs to be dealt with too, probably by removing it.  Drive letters are case-insensitive and `[A-Z]`, AFAIK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The OP hasn't given an indication of what's being fed into the `sed` command (which has a very specific replacement which takes care of the drive letter and the slashes we see). What we don't get to see, we can't provide anything to deal with.

Comment: My comment is at least as much aimed at the OP as it is at you.  Incomplete information leads to answers where the answerer has to guess too much for comfort.  Stripping down to the bare minimum is reasonable, but mentioning plausible other issues is also not unreasonable (though not 100% necessary).  You got my up-vote long ago.

Comment: What's being fed into sed is basically a text location of a server called dept_shares from a Windows user. They send me a file location to my mac and I use that path to convert to a Mac path and open a finder window to it. Sorry I wasn't specific enough, and thanks for the additional info as well since I may actually try to expand it for any drive, not just that one (even though thats the only one I use.

Comment: I played with it a bit more and thought I would share.               'cd "$(echo "$@" | sed -e 's:\\\\[^"\r\n]*:\/Volumes:' -e 's:\\:/:g')"; open .'  This seems to be a bit more flexible. Thanks again for the help folks.